# Is this a property of a log-concave distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F$ be a cdf with associated pdf $f$ on support $[0,b]\subseteq R_+$. Suppose $f$ is log-concave, which implies that $F$ and $1-F$ are also log-concave. Specifically, we have that $\frac{f'}{f}$ is a decreasing function, and $\frac{F}{f}$ is an increasing function. Is $\frac{F}{f}\cdot\frac{f'}{f}$ necessarily a decreasing function?

I have not been able to find a counterexample to the statement in question: I can show that it is true if $f$ is a weakly decreasing function, and it is true for log-concave Weibull and power function distributions (that are not always decreasing). I suspect the statement is true in general but have not been able to prove it. My approach has been to directly compute the derivative of $\frac{F}{f}\cdot\frac{f'}{f}$ to try to sign it. I also have tried to rewrite the function as something like $D\ln[G]$, where $f$ log-concave implies $G$ is log-concave.

Comment: Are you asking whether it’s always the case that at least one of these two functions is decreasing, or whether it’s the case for either of these two functions that it’s always decreasing?

Comment: Whether either one of the functions is a decreasing function (i.e., always decreasing).

Comment: That’s what you already wrote in the question. But that’s ambiguous. You need to specify the order of the quantifiers. Do you want to know whether for every $f$ at least one of these functions is decreasing, or whether one of these functions is decreasing for every $f$?

Comment: I see the ambiguity. I have edited the question to clarify. My main interest is knowing whether the first function in the original question is decreasing, so I only ask about that function.